# Why don't we have 'go to page' function when there are plenty of search results?

Tags: support

When I search Python, there will be more than 6000 pages in search results.
It looks like this

1 2 3 4 5 … 6437 next    15 30 50 per page

If I want to go to page 10, I have to click 5, then 7, then 9, then 10.
It really takes time to find what I want.
Why don't we have  'go to page' function when there are plenty of search results?

Comment: You can play with the URL and get the page you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=10&sort=active&pagesize=15 in code: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=10&sort=active&pagesize=15`

Comment: wow...that's really not ease of use...

Comment: What is so interesting on page 10, and how did you know to look there?

Comment: @Jongware I'd like to browse all the search results to find anything I'm interested on and try to learn or answer. That's where my requirement comes from.

Comment: If you're just browsing search results, why do you need to go directly to page 10?

Comment: @BilltheLizard  Will you do browsing all day? What will you do if you want to continue browsing when you come back from other work while your browser has been closed already?

Comment: Is there something wrong to add an convenient way for browsing? Why voting down??

Comment: Sorry, but the very first comment here gave you a solution (just change the `page=` value in the URL), and your response was "Really? That's too hard!". Changing two digits in a browser URL is *too hard*?

Comment: For hilarity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=1&sort=active&pagesize=1

Comment: @Deduplicator: admittedly, that was hilarious! But, all of my SO search listings immediately **stuck** to this setting => Not so hilarious  (if this happens to you, just click one of the "show xx results" buttons to reset)

Answer (score 14):

You do. Just type `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python?page=10`. I do this all the time.

You're a programmer; you should be able to figure out how to type URLs...

Comment: We should start `url.stackexchange.com` for discussion about url manipulation.

Comment: Only if we don't link to it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I leave it to you to create a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script for this javascript which adds what you want (only tested on IE11). Maybe you are interested in what [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) has on offer as well.

```
(function(){
   $('div.pager')
   .append('<input id="jumper" style="margin:0px;float:left;" size="4" type="number" value="10" />')
   .append(
      $('<a><span class="page-numbers next">jump</span></a>').bind('click', 
          function (e) {
             var i = window.location.href.indexOf('?'), inp = $('input#jumper');
             if (i < 0) {
                i = window.location.href.length;
             }
             window.location.href =  window.location.href.substr(0, i) + "?page=" + inp.val();
             return false;
          } ));
})();
```